# Selenium WebDriver в окне своего приложения

Tags: c#

Меня интересует ответ на такой вопрос.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы окно браузера Selenium WebDrive было именно в моем приложение?

Задумался об написании для себя программы для автоматизации действий в браузере. Но хочу видеть эту работу именно в окне своего приложения.

Что-то вроде такого.
Например, нажал на кнопку проверить курс валют, и открылся сайт с валютами и что-то делает себе. Сейчас все это работает, но открывается отдельное окно Selenium WebDriver и там все происходит. Или это можно сделать как то по другому, не через Selenium WebDriver.
Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Selenium предназначен только для управления полноценным внешним браузером. Встроить в приложение можно либо CEF (Chromium), либо WebView2 (Edge). При этом Selenium не нужен, так как встроенным браузером можно управлять напрямую.

Comment: Хотите автоматизировать действия в браузере - изучайте запросы, как работает конкретный сайт, пишите под это нужные методы взаимодействия, а не надейтесь на что-то "магическое", что возьмет любой сайт, и сделает за вас все. Селениум - это инструмент для автоматического тестирования **своего** ресурса, а не для парсинга курса валюты с чужого сайта. Так что, вот вам направление. Ну а если всеж хотите селениум, то ответ скорей нет, чем да, он не для этого создан.